# Как найти количество слов, начинающихся с заданного префикса

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть задание:

> Дана строка, содержащая английский текст.
>   Найти количество слов, начинающихся с буквы b.

Как его можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с использованием детерминированного конечного автомата:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String text = "banana ttt bbb b qwe";
    int count = 0;
    int state = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            state = 1;
        }
        else if (c == 'b' && state == 1)
        {
            count++;
            state = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            state = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам решение:

```
String text = "hello world banana bank";

String prefix = " b";
int count = 0;
int currentIndex = 0;
while (currentIndex < text.length() 
       && (currentIndex = (text.indexOf(prefix, currentIndex) + 1)) != 0)
    count++;

if(text.startWith(prefix.trim()))
    count++;

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что новичок не разберется с таким if-ом? Разумеется, Вам логика понятна и кажется тривиальной, после того как в голове родилось решение. Только здесь процесс идет наоборот и логика понимается в момент чтения кода.

Comment: Не сломается, строка содержит пробел prefix = " b"

Comment: Задача тривиальна, и автор если бы попытался, вполне смог бы справиться и без нас. Я же предлагаю такое "сложное" решение лишь потому что сам захотел  ее решить более оптимальным способом.

Comment: @Regent спасибо, не внимательно, прочел. да вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть есть строка, содержащая текст

```
string s = "какой-то текст";
```

Тогда используем для разбиения строки метод `split`, предварительно дописав к строке пробел, чтобы последнюю точку учитывать за знак препинания.

```
s += " ";
string[] words = s.split("\\p{P}?[ \\t\\n\\r]+");
```

Далее циклом проходим по массиву и смотрим на первую букву

```
int count = 0;
foreach (string word : words){
    if (word[0] == 'b' || word[0] == 'B')
        count++;
}
```

Comment: создание массива, ихмо не очень оптимально. Хотя можно регулярками искать совпадения и считать

Comment: Не спорю, Ваше решение лучше. Я всего лиль показал один из вариантов

Comment: Меня терзают смутные сомнения: либо вы писали код не на _Java_, либо вы его не проверяли. Весьма похоже на _C#_.

Comment: А разве можно проверять тип `String` оператором `==`. Не `equals` ли?

Comment: @СергейГрушин а где здесь идет сравнение `String` через `==` ?

Comment: @СергейГрушин а где здесь `String`? Здесь `string`, которого в _Java_ попросту нет. А вот в _C#_ конструкция `word[0]` вернёт первый `char` в строке, который является примитивов и который можно сравнивать с помощью `==`.